# Finding the equation for a multiple and nonlinear regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression, model-selection, data-science-model

Regarding nonlinear and multivariable regression, I am using R or Matlab. In the case where I have a regression with just two variables, I simply draw the graph Y with respect to X and look for the equation of the model that corresponds the most to the distribution of the point cloud.

However, in the case where Y is connected with several independent variables (in my case 12 variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_{12}$). How will I be able to define the equation of the regression model?

Answer (score 0):

This question clearly is the basics of linear regression.

If you are looking for a way to implement linear regression in R, use the lm method.

```
fit <- lm(y~X1+X2, data = datasetname)

summary(fit)
```

This should give the coefficients and the p value for each variable.

Comment: But the title is clear, the question is about nonlinear regression.

Comment: I apologize.  that is not the solution for your question. consider taking interactive terms.